# Screen refresh during code execution

Tags: android, eclipse, button, layout

Is there a command in android for refreshing the whole layout or jut one element, something like refresh command in Visual Basic.

```
public void buttonAction(int buttonId){

Button btn=getButtonFromId(buttonId);
btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//here need some kind of screen refreshing in order to change the color
//... some long time executing code goes here
btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


}
```

The text color never changes to RED

Comment: what is the default text color?

Answer (score 0):

Call `invalidate` on view object

Call it on any view it will redraw entire screen.

```
btn.invalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the quickest answer I ever got. (less then 1 minute)

Comment: If the answer is correct, Please mark the answer and upvote it.